# ext4 Filesystem drive not recognised

Tags: centos, windows, ext4

I have an ext4 drive formatted on a server running CentOS to record content, which is then used to insert in a server running Win10 version 1607 to transfer files.

However, when this drive is inserted back in the server running CentOS, the drive loses its RAID config. and needs to be added back using the RAID config utility and reformatted.

This issue is specific only to this server on which Win10 is running. If I use the same drive on any other Win10 machine, there is no problem and the drive is recognised when inserted back in the server running CentOS

I am using DiskInternals Linux reader and it's mounted as read-only. But even if I don't use this tool, and just insert the drive in the server and remove it, the RAID is still lost. It's only a single 6TB drive and it's configured using hardware RAID. Again, this behaviour is only with this server with Win10 on it. Its a Supermicro X11SSL-F. The Win10 client is set to AHCI mode and I have tried using a USB3 port with SATA to USB adapter, and the issue still persists.

Any ideas what could be the issue here please?

Comment: how is the drive partitioned exactly and which flavor of RAID are we talking about?

Comment: Its Raid0 and the drive is partitioned using ‘’’parted /dev/sdb mklabel gpt’’’

Comment: Does the problem-causing Win10 system have a RAID controller of any kind? It might be overwriting the RAID configuration of the CentOS system with its own RAID disk identifier, making it unrecognizable to the CentOS system's RAID implementation, which apparently isn't quite as eager to claim "new" disks as its own without permission. If hardware RAID is involved at any point, it would be important to know the make and model of the RAID controller(s) involved.

Comment: I am using DiskInternals Linux reader and it's mounted as read-only. But even if I don't use this tool, and just insert the drive in the server and remove it, the RAID is still lost. It's only a single 6TB drive and it's configured using hardware RAID. Again, this behaviour is only with this server with Win10 on it. Its  a Supermicro X11SSL-F.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake, Win10 has Standard AHCI Host Controller and under boot settings, it's set to AHCI mode

Comment: Would be interesting to know if the "other" Windows 10 client also has a built-in RAID controller, and if so whether it's the same make/model as the one that's "misbehaving". Unfortunately since this is hardware RAID I'm not sure if anyone's going to be able to help you with a definitive answer - there are just too many variations out there.